# Angular filter by dynamic columns

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have filter function which is working just fine when I use static column name in it like:

```
this.listOfData = this.listOfData.filter((item: DataItem) =>
  item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(newValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1
);
```

PS: `item.name`

But I need to search in every column of the `item`, **how can I do that?**

PS: `name` should be dynamic.

My `ListofData` has this columns:

```
listOfData({
  id: 
  ticket_number: 
  status_name:
  name: // currently my function is set to this value only.
  created_by_full_name:
  receive_time:
  response_time:
  resolution_time:
})
```

## Update

based on `Allabakash` answer I have final code below which returning lots of typescript error:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  // this listens to the input value from the service and does something on change.
  this.globalSearchService.searchTerm.subscribe((newValue: string) => {
    // this is where you would apply your existing filtering.
    this.searchTerm = newValue;
    if(newValue != null) {
      this.visible = false
      this.listOfData = this.listOfData.filter((item: DataItem) =>
      let keys = Object.keys(item);
      for (let key of keys) {
         if (typeof item[key] === 'string' && 
           item[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(newValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
           return true;
         }
       }
       return false;
      );
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to search on all properties dynamically, you can try something like this.

```js
this.listOfData = this.listOfData.filter((item: DataItem) => {
     let keys = Object.keys(item);
     for (let key of keys) {
       if (typeof item[key] === 'string' && 
         item[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(newValue.toLowerCase()) !== -1) {
         return true;
       }
     }
     return false;
    }
  );
```

Comment: thanks, but it gives lots of typescript errors such as `,` or `Declaration or statement expected`. i will update my question based on your answer

Comment: can you wrap the filter function inside code within {} braces

Comment: sorry didn't understand what you said

Comment: updated the answer, where braces were missing, can you try that

Comment: sure, create new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **ES6** for a one liner solution. Below is a sample using **vanilla Javascript**

```js
    const initialListOfData = [
      { name: 'Peter', surname: 'John'},
      { name: 'Judas', surname: 'James'},
      { name: 'Paul', surname: 'Peter'},
      { name: 'Petrover', surname: 'Junior'}
    ]

    const searchItem = 'pet'

    const listOfData = initialListOfData.filter(
      item => Object.keys(item).some(prop => 
        (new RegExp(searchItem.toLowerCase())).test(item[prop].toLowerCase())
    ))

    console.log(listOfData)
```

For your Problem using typescript this will be

```typescript
this.listOfData = initialListOfData.filter(
   (item: any) => Object.keys(item).some((prop: any) => 
     (new RegExp(newValue.toLowerCase())).test(item[prop].toLowerCase())
 ))
```